# Passing an executable function reference to/from a child Svelte component?

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-component

**Hi. How might I accomplish this loop successfully?**

1. pass a function name from a parent component to a child component
2. have the child component return function name on an event (e.g. click)
3. execute the function name (now a string) within the parent component

An example of needing this would be using something like a DropdownMenu component in an Application Header – where the header has a logout link/handler that is passed to the menu with a mix of other href links/actions.

Here's a REPL example of the approach I'm taking currently (using `window[functionName]`) which isn't working yet –

https://svelte.dev/repl/280626d841d84dd08dd944ec249e4e6f?version=3.38.2

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the solution to this is to simply not pass the functions from the parent component as strings.

Passing them as literal references and calling these within the child component generically, works.

Updated REPL of working version -

https://svelte.dev/repl/5b8bb118e0aa47d38d974cbc1fd23453?version=3.38.2